# How to compare with Case in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Here am having Person and Address Tables .Some Persons may have address or not.If they have address then want to join address table otherwise no need to join.Please help to solve this case.

```
select p.name,nvl(a.address,'address not available') from person p,address a
where p.id = 2 and case
            when p.addid is not null
              then   p.addid = a.id
             else 0=0 end
```

Comment: how about using peron p left join address a on p.addid = a.id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *general solution* - use Boolean logic. You cannot choose between complete expressions using CASE, so you should rewrite it to use a combination of AND and OR. Using the logic from your question, you would rewrite it as:

```
WHERE p.id = 2
AND 
(
    (p.addid IS NOT NULL AND p.addid = a.id)
    OR (p.addid IS NULL AND 0=0)
)
```

Which ultimately simplifies down to:

```
WHERE p.id = 2
AND (p.addid IS NULL OR p.addid = a.id)
```

---

The *specific solution for your query* - use better JOIN syntax, and simply leverage a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT p.name, nvl(a.address,'address not available')
FROM person p
LEFT OUTER JOIN address a ON p.addid = a.id
WHERE p.id = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **coalesce** function as below

```
select p.name,nvl(a.address,'address not available') from person p,address a
where p.id = 2 
and coalesce(p.addid,a.id)=a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select p.name, nvl(a.address, 'address not available') 
from person p left outer join address a 
   on (p.addid = a.id )
where p.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use case, but you can achieve the same effect with combination of `or`s sand `and`s

```
select p.name,
       nvl(a.address,'address not available')
  from person p,
       address a
 where p.id = 2 and 
       ( p.addid is not null AND p.addid = a.id 
         OR 
         p.addid is null
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select p.name,nvl(a.address,'address not available') from person p,address a
where p.id = 2 and a.id = case when p.addid is not null then p.addid else a.id end;
```